# Why does scrolling a ViewPager before changing it's padding and pagemargin completely jack it up?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, kotlin

I want to be able to toggle my viewpager between two different states. One state where the fragment takes up the entire screen, and the second state where it shows previews of the fragments on either side. 
The following is the desired effect: https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-d5afc38aa7.gif

Notice that the gif is only for the first item in the viewpager. Watch what happens when I scroll to another item in the viewpager before attempting to switch states: https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-bf17757173.gif
As you can see I was on the item labelled "2" and it "zoomed out" to some incorrect point in the second state.

The following is my code (in Kotlin):

```
fun setupListeners() {
    btnTest.setOnClickListener {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.viewPager)
        if(stateTwo) {
            resetViewPagerStyling()
        } else {
            setViewPagerStateTwo()
        }

        stateTwo = !stateTwo
    }
}

fun setViewPagerInStateTwo() {
    // Setup view pager to show siblings
    viewPager.clipToPadding = false
    // Setup margins to show pages to the side
    viewPager.setPadding(100, 100, 100, 100)
    viewPager.pageMargin = 50
}

fun resetViewPagerStyling() {
    // Setup view pager to show siblings
    viewPager.clipToPadding = true
    // Reset margin and padding to 0
    viewPager.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
    viewPager.pageMargin = 0
}
```

Comment: Are either of `setViewPagerInStateTwo()` or `resetViewPagerStyling()` being called when you swipe the `ViewPager`?

Comment: @azizbekian Nope.